# Persist nested list of objects into the same table JPA hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I've started working with JPA(Hibernate). I'm trying to map a nested list of objects in my class to a table. Tried the following based on my understanding. When I googled, I could find some solutions based on having two different tables for each entity and joining them. However I want to maintain a single table for the following setup.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Attendance")
public class Attendance
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    int id;
    
    @Embedded
    @OneToMany
    List<SessionsMissed> days;
    
    //Other members, getters, setters

}

@Embeddable
public Class SessionsMissed{

    @Column(name="Date")
    String date;

    @Column(name="Session1")    
    String presentForOne;
  
    @Column(name="Session2")    
    String presentForTwo;
    
    //Other members, getters, setters
}
```

This issue is probably due to my lack of understanding of the concepts and that I'm not searching with proper keywords. Appreciate any help. When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.demo.entities.Attendance.days[com.demo.entities.SessionsMissed]

Error Stack:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.demo.entities.Attendance.days[com.demo.entities.SessionsMissed]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.demo.demoApplication.main(demoApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.demo.entities.Attendance.days[com.demo.entities.SessionsMissed]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1351) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:874) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

`One To Many` attribute value type **should not be `Embeddable`**.

If you want to use embeddable type you can do the **`@ElementCollection`**:

> **@ElementCollection** is mainly for mapping non-entities (embeddable or
> basic) while **@OneToMany** is used to map entities.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Attendance")
public class Attendance {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    int id;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<SessionsMissed> days;

    // getter / setter ..
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class SessionsMissed {

    @Column(name = "Date")
    String date;

    @Column(name = "Session1")
    String presentForOne;
  
    @Column(name = "Session2")    
    String presentForTwo;

    // getter / setter ..
}
```

You can take a look at the short and detailed explanations of the definitions. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-jpa-elementcollection

Comment: The code runs now but the columns pertaining to SessionsMissed class are null in the table. And a separate table for that class gets created with the "Id" from Attendance class being referenced as foreign key. I'm looking to have one single table instead.

Comment: Check here **if you want to keep one `SessionsMissed` entity**. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable I think you need more than one by looking at your model structure. You need to use `@ ElementCollection` in it, and this provides multiple tables and relationships.